# Better way to say: "Coronavirus is a case for an emergency fund"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I have this word in my mind that I believe is used for occasions like the current pandemic and saving or building up an emergency fund. You could say something like:

> The coronavirus crisis is [X] for an emergency fund.

But I just can't put my finger on the word that is usually used. I believe it's somewhere along the lines of "a case" but I don't think it's that exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***makes a case***

> to argue that something is the best thing to do, giving your reasons:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-case-for-sth)

...from your question:

> I believe it's somewhere along the lines of "a case"

The coronavirus crisis *makes a case* for (having) an emergency fund.

Comment: "makes a case" sounds better to me.

Comment: If one says that the crisis makes a case for something, one is speaking metaphorically. As the quoted definition makes clear, making a case is something that a **person** does; only a person can (literally) argue and give reasons.

Comment: I made this the solution since it's  the one closest to what I was i thinking about and that I can actually flag as a solution (the comment in my question was good as well but it's a comment...)

Answer (score 0):

Saying *a case* doesn't quite make sense. You might be thinking of *a cause*.

But that doesn't work well either. I like *a reason*.

Comment: Yes, but I thought there is a word that especially newspapers or opinion pieces use for this kind of sentence. It might be cause...

Answer (score 0):

*The coronavirus crisis is a strong **contender** for an emergency fund.*

An example of the broadened, non-sentient usage:

- These successful revisions show that the activation-synthesis model is still the main contender among models seeking to show how dreams are generated.
  From Cambridge English Corpus

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/contender)]

(ie the one most likely to be considered valid / accepted)

Comment: Note that the OP is speaking of 'saving or building up an emergency fund', i.e. of creating the resources for emergencies. This answer seems to assume that the resources are already in existence, and that it only needs to be decided how they should be allocated.

Comment: No; it assumes that emergency funds are available options. There is a strong argument that [setting up] an emergency fund is the right response. Note Rattler's parallel response (which for some reason didn't attract a downvote): 'The coronavirus crisis makes a case for (having) an emergency fund.' The covert 'having' / 'setting up' is covert here precisely because OP has restricted the phraseology.

Comment: Indeed there is an implied idea of **setting up** something (that does not yet exist) in both the question and the other answers (however imperfect they may otherwise be). That, however, seems to be at odds with he word *contender*, which implies that there is a (literal or metaphorical) contest, competition, which in turn implies that **there is** (already in existence) something that different contenders are competing **for**.

Comment: @jsw29 If something can't be a contender, I don't see how it can make a case. One sense of 'contend' is 'argue one's case'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/contend) has: (2) 'assert something as a position in an argument.' Obviously, there's metaphorical broadening involved.